# How to choose the right neural network in a binary classification problem for a unbalanced data?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am using `keras sequential` model for binary classification. But My data is unbalanced. I have 2 features column and 1 output column(1/0). I have 10000 of data. Among that only 20 results in output 1, all others are 0. Then i have extended the data size to 40000. Now also only 20 results in output 1, all others are 0. Since the data is unbalanced(0 dominates 1), which neural network will be better for correct prediction?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, two features is a really small amount. Neural Networks are highly non-linear models with a really really high amount of freedom degrees, thus if you try to train a network with more than just a couple of networks it will overfit even with balanced classes. You can find more suitable models for a small dimensionality like Support Vector Machines in scikit-learn library.

Now about unbalanced data, the most common techniques are Undersampling and Oversampling. Undersampling is basically training your model several times with a fraction of the dataset, that contains the non dominant class and a random sample of the dominant so that the ratio is acceptable, where as oversampling consist on generating artificial data to balance the classes. In most cases undersampling works better.

Also when working with unbalanced data it's quite important to choose the right metric based on what is more important for the problem (is minimizing false positives more important than false negatives, etc).